# SASS and @font-face

Tags: css, sass

I have the following CSS - how would I describe it in SASS? I've tried reverse compiling it with css2sass, and just keep getting errors.... is it my CSS (which works ;-) )?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bingo';
    src: url("bingo.eot");
    src: local('bingo'),
       url("bingo.svg#bingo") format('svg'),
       url("bingo.otf") format('opentype');
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering - it was probably my css...

```
@font-face
  font-family: "bingo"
  src: url('bingo.eot')
  src: local('bingo')
  src: url('bingo.svg#bingo') format('svg')
  src: url('bingo.otf') format('opentype')
```

will render as

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "bingo";
  src: url('bingo.eot');
  src: local('bingo');
  src: url('bingo.svg#bingo') format('svg');
  src: url('bingo.otf') format('opentype'); }
```

which seems to be close enough... just need to check the SVG rendering

Answer (score 52):

I’ve been struggling with this for a while now. Dycey’s solution is correct in that specifying the `src` multiple times outputs the same thing in your css file. However, this seems to break in OSX Firefox 23 (probably other versions too, but I don’t have time to test).

The cross-browser `@font-face` solution from [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) looks like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontname';
    src: url('fontname.eot');
    src: url('fontname.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fontname.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fontname.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fontname.svg#fontname') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

To produce the `src` property with the comma-separated values, you need to write all of the values on one line, since line-breaks are not supported in Sass. To produce the above declaration, you would write the following Sass:

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'fontname'
  src: url('fontname.eot')
  src: url('fontname.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fontname.woff') format('woff'), url('fontname.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fontname.svg#fontname') format('svg')
  font-weight: normal
  font-style: normal
```

I think it seems silly to write out the path a bunch of times, and I don’t like overly long lines in my code, so I worked around it by writing this mixin:

```
=font-face($family, $path, $svg, $weight: normal, $style: normal)
  @font-face
    font-family: $family
    src: url('#{$path}.eot')
    src: url('#{$path}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('#{$path}.woff') format('woff'), url('#{$path}.ttf') format('truetype'), url('#{$path}.svg##{$svg}') format('svg')
    font-weight: $weight
    font-style: $style
```

**Usage**: For example, I can use the previous mixin to setup up the Frutiger Light font like this:

```
+font-face('frutigerlight', '../fonts/frutilig-webfont', 'frutigerlight')
```

Comment: Interesting! My intranet users aren't using FF so hasn't noticed the issue. Will look into it

Comment: I ran into an issue where the accepted solution wasn't working in IE9 and 10, but your suggestion to put all of the `src`s on one line fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: im getting this error Invalid CSS after "    src: ": expected "{", was "url('#{$path}.e..."

Comment: @Jezen Thomas Your example include path, but doesn't include font-family `url('#{$path}.eot')` result: `src: url('#{../fonts/frutilig-webfont.eot')` Please fix

Comment: Thank you very much!

> To produce the src property with the comma-separated values, you need to write all of the values on one line, since line-breaks are not supported in Sass.

Answer (score 8):

For those looking for an SCSS mixin instead, including *woff2*, [SASS **list.append**](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list) is useful for conditionally adding source files/formats:

```
@mixin fface(
  $path,
  $family,
  $type: "",
  $weight: 400,
  $style: normal,
  $local1: null,
  $local2: null,
  $ttf: null,
  $otf: null,
  $eot: null,
  $svg: null
) {
  $src: null; // initialize an empty source path
  // only load local files when both sources are present
  @if $local1 and $local2 {
    $src: append($src, local("#{$local1}"), comma);
    $src: append($src, local("#{$local2}"), comma);
  }

  @if $otf {
    $src: append($src, url("#{$path}#{$type}.otf") format("opentype"), comma);
  }

  // load default formats (woff and woff2)
  $src: append($src, url("#{$path}#{$type}.woff2") format("woff2"), comma);
  $src: append($src, url("#{$path}#{$type}.woff") format("woff"), comma);
  // formats that should only be added at the end
  @if $ttf {
    $src: append($src, url("#{$path}#{$type}.ttf") format("truetype"), comma);
  }

  @if $svg {
    $src: append($src, url("#{$path}#{$type}.svg##{$svg}") format("svg"), comma);
  }
  // the actual FONT FACE DECLARATION
  @font-face {
    font-family: $family;
    // for compatibility reasons EOT comes first and is not appended
    @if $eot {
      src: url("#{$path}#{$type}.eot");
    }
    // load appended sources path
    src: $src;
    font-weight: $weight;
    font-style: $style;
  }
}
// USAGE
$dir: "assets/fonts/";

// declare family name
$familyName: "MyFont";

@include fface(
  "#{$dir}#{$familyName}", $familyName, "-regular", 400, "normal",
  "#{$familyName} Regular", "#{$familyName}-Regular", "ttf", "otf"
);

@include fface(
  "#{$dir}#{$familyName}", $familyName, "-medium", 500, "normal",
  "#{$familyName} Medium", "#{$familyName}-Medium", "ttf", "otf"
);

@include fface(
  "#{$dir}#{$familyName}", $familyName, "-semibold", 600, "normal",
  "#{$familyName} SemiBold", "#{$familyName}-SemiBold", "ttf", "otf"
);

// Material Icons
$familyName: "Material Icons"; // override previous value
$familyFileName: "MaterialIcons";

@include fface(
  "#{$dir}#{$familyFileName}", $familyName, "-regular", 400, "normal",
  $familyName, "#{$familyFileName}-Regular", "ttf", null, "eot"
);
@include fface(
  "#{$dir}#{$familyFileName}", "#{$familyName} Outline", "-outline", 400, "normal",
  "#{$familyName} Outline", "#{$familyFileName}-Outline", null, "otf", "eot"
);

.material-icons {
  font-family: $familyName;
}

.material-icons-outline {
  font-family: "#{$familyName} Outline";
}
```

The `$type` parameter is used for locating different files within a `$family`.

If you get a *can't resolve* error, remember to double check your fonts directory (`$dir`).

Answer (score 4):

In my case I use **SASS Mixin**:

```
@mixin font-face($family, $file, $path, $svg, $weight: normal, $style: normal)
  @font-face
    font-family: $family
    src: url($path + $file + '.eot')
    src: url($path + $file + '.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url($path + $file + '.woff') format('woff'), url($path + $file + '.ttf') format('truetype'), url($path + $file + '.svg##{$svg}') format('svg')
    font-weight: $weight
    font-style: $style
```

**Usage**:

```
@include font-face('altivo', 'altivo-regular', '', 'altivo-regular')
@include font-face('altivo', 'altivo-medium', '', 'altivo-medium', 500, normal)
@include font-face('altivo', 'altivo-bold', '', 'altivo-bold', 700, normal)
@include font-face('corsa', 'corsa-grotesk-regular', '', 'corsa-grotesk-regular')
@include font-face('corsa', 'corsa-grotesk-medium', '', 'corsa-grotesk-medium', 500, normal)
@include font-face('corsa', 'corsa-grotesk-bold', '', 'corsa-grotesk-bold', 700, normal)
@include font-face('corsa', 'corsa-grotesk-xbold', '', 'corsa-grotesk-xbold', 800, normal)
```

**Result**:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "altivo";
  src: url("altivo-regular.eot");
  src: url("altivo-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("altivo-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("altivo-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("altivo-regular.svg#altivo-regular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "altivo";
  src: url("altivo-medium.eot");
  src: url("altivo-medium.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("altivo-medium.woff") format("woff"), url("altivo-medium.ttf") format("truetype"), url("altivo-medium.svg#altivo-medium") format("svg");
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "altivo";
  src: url("altivo-bold.eot");
  src: url("altivo-bold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("altivo-bold.woff") format("woff"), url("altivo-bold.ttf") format("truetype"), url("altivo-bold.svg#altivo-bold") format("svg");
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "corsa";
  src: url("corsa-grotesk-regular.eot");
  src: url("corsa-grotesk-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("corsa-grotesk-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("corsa-grotesk-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("corsa-grotesk-regular.svg#corsa-grotesk-regular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "corsa";
  src: url("corsa-grotesk-medium.eot");
  src: url("corsa-grotesk-medium.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("corsa-grotesk-medium.woff") format("woff"), url("corsa-grotesk-medium.ttf") format("truetype"), url("corsa-grotesk-medium.svg#corsa-grotesk-medium") format("svg");
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "corsa";
  src: url("corsa-grotesk-bold.eot");
  src: url("corsa-grotesk-bold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("corsa-grotesk-bold.woff") format("woff"), url("corsa-grotesk-bold.ttf") format("truetype"), url("corsa-grotesk-bold.svg#corsa-grotesk-bold") format("svg");
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "corsa";
  src: url("corsa-grotesk-xbold.eot");
  src: url("corsa-grotesk-xbold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("corsa-grotesk-xbold.woff") format("woff"), url("corsa-grotesk-xbold.ttf") format("truetype"), url("corsa-grotesk-xbold.svg#corsa-grotesk-xbold") format("svg");
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).