# How to link a Google font to my Nuxt files?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

Im new to SCSS and im trying to load a local font to my SCSS file.

This works perfectly fine in a CSS file but in a SCSS file it does not give anything, not even an error:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cairo";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url(./assets/Fonts/Cairo/CairoBlock-Regular.ttf);
}
```

The css and scss files are both located in the same directory so the path should be same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is that `../assets/https:/font...`? It's not a local import. And I'm not even sure that you can import a CDN directly like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to efficiently load google fonts in Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165911/how-to-efficiently-load-google-fonts-in-nuxt)

Comment: I updated the question. I decided to try to load all fonts locally.

Comment: What do you see in the DOM (devtools)? It's not applied? Also, did you checked this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1567184/8816585 ?

Comment: It's not applied. I checked that but I'm using the other syntax.

Comment: Is there something fundamental I could be missing maybe? I have only installed sass globally but nothing else.

Comment: Oh, I was using this @nuxtjs/style-resources module in the nuxt config and I tried to set set all the scss files from styleResources: [] to the css: [] in nuxt config and everything starter working magically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your fonts loaded properly, you need to have them linked to your page somehow at some point. Hence why putting your SCSS files into the [`css` property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-css#the-css-property) is probably the way to go.

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: ['put-your-files-here']
}
```

Otherwise, here is [how to load some fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166329/8816585) properly with Nuxt.